# Selenium Cucumber integration with Test Link using Jenkins build tool

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, testlink

Is there a way to integrate the cucumber scenarios results to Test link ?

As of now , it is possible to give the J unit class file names (Step Definitions) in the jenkins test link configuration and able to update the results. 
But the problem is as Feature contains many number of scenarios , want to update the test link cases using scenario level results not the complete feature result .
Just for Info :

This can be solved by using different step definitions for different scenarios , but going forward ill end up with thousands of classes.

Is there a way a auto update test link cases using cucumber Json output reports ???

Help is Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is usually Testlink xor cucumber. Why are you trying to integrate them?

Comment: For my project i have to use cucumber framework and i need the overall pass percentages and reports with different combinations and detailed sprint wise features.  Cucumber features files needs to be saved in eclipse  and no one from management could see them.